# Unexpected behavior when querying the PID of bash or zsh when using the --command/-c flag

Tags: bash, shell, process, zsh

I am observing odd behavior when examining the PID of certain shells when executed in a non-interpreted context.

In the below examples, I see that the PID is pointing to the shell, as expected.

```bsh
sh-4.3$ echo 'readlink /proc/$$/exe' | /bin/bash
/bin/bash
sh-4.3$ echo 'readlink /proc/$$/exe' | /bin/tcsh
/bin/tcsh
sh-4.3$ echo 'readlink /proc/$$/exe' | /bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

However, if I try the same idea using `-c` instead of a pipe, the PID in Bourne-compatible shells is for `readlink` instead of the shell.

```bsh
sh-4.3$ /bin/tcsh -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe'
/bin/tcsh
sh-4.3$ /bin/bash -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe'
/usr/bin/readlink
sh-4.3$ /bin/zsh -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe'
/usr/bin/readlink
```

I have also found that if I make the command a compound statement instead of a single statement then I get the results I expect most of the time (`zsh` appears to be a bit more stubborn).

```bsh
sh-4.3$ /bin/bash -cf 'readlink /proc/$$/exe | cat'
/bin/bash
sh-4.3$ /bin/zsh -cf 'readlink /proc/$$/exe | cat'
/usr/bin/zsh
sh-4.3$ /bin/bash -cf 'readlink /proc/$$/exe; :'
/bin/bash
sh-4.3$ /bin/zsh -cf 'readlink /proc/$$/exe; :'
/bin/zsh
sh-4.3$ /bin/bash -cf ':; readlink /proc/$$/exe'
/bin/bash
sh-4.3$ /bin/zsh -cf ':; readlink /proc/$$/exe'
/usr/bin/readlink
sh-4.3$ /bin/bash -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe > /dev/stdout'
/bin/bash
sh-4.3$ /bin/zsh -c 'readlink /proc/$$/exe > /dev/stdout'
/usr/bin/readlink
```

I suspect what is happening is that the Bourne-compatible shells are checking if the call can be performed as a single statement and if so using [`execv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) or somesuch instead of actually invoking the shell.

My questions:

- Is my suspicion correct? If so, what might have been the motivation for this?
- Can I disable this behavior?

Comment: "Can I disable this behavior?" – what for? I'm asking because in general [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) is a thing.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski More as a curiosity than anything else. This behavior is not blocking or preventing me from doing anything, but it violated my Principle of Least Surprise.  I am wondering if it can be disabled since I (naively) assume that any surprising behavior should have a switch to disable it. I was imagining a case where I *needed* the same behavior for both tcsh and zsh, or something crazy like that.

Comment: Very similar: [Strange behavior of \`/proc/self/environ\` in some shells; what is going on?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/467169)